# Coupled Differential Equations - manipulate many parameters

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, manipulate, nonlinear

I have a system of three ODE's. I want to model the population growth of algae (top equation) that is dependent on the next equation, which is dependent on the following equation. Is there a way to dynamically manipulate a graph by sweeping through different values of all the constants?

The system is

```
{n'[t] == (r (n[t]) (1 - (n[t]/K)))/(1 - (n[t]/((c[t]/b) - n[t]))), 
 c'[t] == k (o[t]) - g (c[t]) - m (c[t]), 
 o'[t] == G (c[t]) n[t] - q (n[t]) - h (o[t]) + u}
```

---

The system in traditional form:

[image: traditional format looks like this]

Comment: yes, there is. But your question does not provide complete information. You should list the control variables you want to manipulate and the allowed range for these variables so someone does not have to guess. Look up Manipulate also in the help, lots of examples.

Comment: In addition to the advise of Nasser, you must fix somehow the initial conditions. Further, you have 8 parameters. This number of parameters makes the further analysis extremely difficult. I would predict that you will succeed when you white a code, but fail when you start your analysis. You may, however, decrease the number of control parameters by re-scaling both your dependent variables and time. If you are lucky after the re-scaling you may have 4 control parameters instead of 8, and this is already doable. The last advice: use `k` instead of `K`.

Comment: Have look at `ParametricNDSolve` and `ParametricNDSolveValue` in the documentation (they do essentially the same but represent the solutions in different forms).

Comment: When you look at the answer of Matthias, you see that he *guessed* what you should have provided: Initial conditions and parameter values. Since this is already your second question that has several close votes, I suggest you visit the [help center](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help) and read what makes a good question. We dearly want to help you, but we expect that you at least provide all information that are necessary to give you meaningful answers.

Comment: @halirutan I would not be so strict concerning the parameters. When I have differential equations it often helps me to put them into Mathematica without too much understanding and play around with the parameters to see how it behaves. What I had to guess was the meaning of the functions. I was guessing that these are some kind of rate equations and that the functions are some kind of concentrations from 0 to 1. So, this information is really missing plus some background of the context. On the positive side there was no error concerning the equations.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `NDSolve` and `Manipulate`. For example:

```
DynamicModule[{eqns, init, sol, n, c, o, t}, Manipulate[
  eqns = {
    n'[t] == (r (n[t]) (1 - (n[t]/K)))/(1 - (n[t]/((c[t]/b) - n[t]))),
    c'[t] == k (o[t]) - g (c[t]) - m (c[t]),
    o'[t] == G (c[t]) n[t] - q (n[t]) - h (o[t]) + u};
  init = {n[0] == n0, c[0] == c0, o[0] == o0};
  sol = NDSolve[{eqns, init}, {n, c, o}, {t, 0, 30}];
  Plot[Evaluate[{n[t], c[t], o[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 30}, PlotLegends -> Placed[{"n[t]", "c[t]", "o[t]"}, Scaled[{0.9, 0.5}]]]
  , {{r, 1}, 0, 2}, {{K, 1}, 0, 2}, {{b, 1}, 0, 2}, {{k, 1}, 0, 2}, {{g, 1}, 0, 2},
  {{m, 1}, 0, 2}, {{G, 1}, 0, 2}, {{q, 1}, 0, 2}, {{h, 1}, 0, 2}, {{u, 1}, 0, 2},
  Delimiter, "initial conditions", {{n0, 0.5}, 0, 1}, {{c0, 0}, 0, 1}, {{o0, 1}, 0, 1}]]
```

[image]